# Best approach to database and UI development?

Tags: sql-server, forms, database-design, calendar, relational-database

This question covers a number of areas, so may ultimately have to broken up into constituent parts. However, I don't want to do this, at least until I have some general idea of what direction I should be taking!

I want to create an **online booking system** under the .Net Framework. The GUI would have two separate vital areas. 1. would be the **typical form GUI for setting up a user account**. 2. would be **a Calendar** (much in the same vein as Google Calendar - if not actually Google Calendar) **which would show users available times that users can book**, and hopefully allow them to actually book by simply clicking on an available time as displayed on the calendar.

The available times that would be displayed on the calendar would depend on two things: the type of user the user is (would be specified in the signup form) and also (obviously) whether or not other users have already taken available slots.

One big question I have is whether it is possible to use Microsoft Access (any version) for this task. My preference is due to familiarity, and the fact that most other technologies being used in this development are Microsoft based. I know it is possible to migrate Access DBs with SQL Server - but would this include the vital front end (i.e. the form)?

Finally, The strategy for approaching the calendar aspect of the front-end is doing my head in a little! While it is certainly possible to integrate SQL Server and Google (docs/calendar) I feel that attempting to shoehorn Google Calendar into such a complex relational database would be ultimately infeasible - but I am struggling to think of an alternative without having to do my own development (which, in this case, I am seriously attempting to avoid!)

Any guidance on the above would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the sake of clarification: is there any material difference between the process of migration used by SQL Server Migration and that of Expression Web 4.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to use Microsoft Access (any version) for this task, the task being using Access as the database for a  online booking system under the .Net Framework: **Yes. (But I would prefer to use MSSQL Express Edition)**

I know it is possible to migrate Access DBs with SQL Server - but would this include the vital front end (i.e. the form)?: **No, SQL Server has not concept of "forms". If you already have them in Access you would have to re-create them in, for example, ASP.NET. If you are looking for the easiest fastest way to do it, I would recommend you LightSwitch ( http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch )**

Finally, The strategy for approaching the calendar aspect of the front-end is doing my head in a little!: **If you do no want to code it, you can find it in Google, just write ".NET Schedule control"**

Comment: Access can not seriously be used when you want to go shared hosting - good luck finding a host supporting access.

Comment: @TomTom Access is just a file you can put in ~App_Data folder and use via web.config. Although, i wonder if it's transactional... heh. Anyhow, point is that I don't know of any hosting that won't work with it.

Comment: 'Hosting' surely wouldn't be an issue though if migrated? Thanks Luxspes for pointing out LightSwitch - will definitely take a look. The website I am developing is under the Umbraco CMS, which is in asp.net, so it should fit nicely (notwithstanding the fact that CMSs are not known for things... fitting.. easily)

Comment: @JDPeckham Access is NOT just a file. Access is "justa file plus a native driver that must be installed on the computer". Now, if that is not installed and you can not install it, that sort of kills the "just a file" theory as stupid, or? And sorry, since some time having the drivers installed is NOT common on windows hosts.

Answer (score 2):

My $.02: as @Luxspes said, Sql Server has no "forms" or "reports", but the SQL Server engine is better suited to web-based applications than Access's "Jet" engine. You could, however, develop your application in Access and then "upsize" your database, which tells Access "hey, those forms and reports are great, but now I want you to put the back-end database into SQL Server Express (free) and keep the front-end in Access." You can then publish your forms and reports to the web using Access's own tools, getting them "for free" while getting the better database engine on the back.

Be aware that doing this is **not** generally acceptable in the commercial world. An Access application looks like an Access application and most of the world will recognize it, and most don't like it: it will seem like you're cutting corners unless you can make the forms look really, really good. For in-house use it's fine because it has a fast turn-around time so the ROI is great. If you're making a commercial site, I'd take a look at the Microsoft MVC 3 framework: it will take a while to get your noodle around it, but once you're up to speed you can develop sites pretty quickly and robustly. If "robustly" is a word.

Comment: Hmmm... amateurish looks are a bit of a no-no in these circumstances unfortunately. I presume you mean the aesthetics (of forms), and specifically for users?

Comment: Exactly, though I haven't played with Access 2012 yet. The older forms were functional and you had some control over the aesthetics, but not much. It may be better in 2012.